# API to update the OSM database

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to update the OSM database (upstream) if I couldn't find the address of latlng using Nominatim using either Android/IoS/Webapp.

Please help me how to achieve it using API.

Thanks.

Comment: Update which database exactly? Please be more specific. Your local OSM database or the main OSM database?

Comment: I want to update the upstream OSM DB, so that next time I update the local OSM DB, it is available to me and rest of the world.

Comment: The API is documented at [API v0.6](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6). What have you tried so far and where are you stuck exactly? Also please keep the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines) in mind. If in doubt, use one of the [OSM editors](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editors).

Comment: I need to try out, I was looking for an example app if someone has achieved it and could share the git repo of it to try and test.

Comment: (Almost?) All of the previously mentioned OSM editors are open source. Feel free to take a look at their source.

Answer (score 0):

After too much search. I found the api usage in [github](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/search?q=%2Fapi%2F0.6%2Fchangeset%2Fcreate&unscoped_q=%2Fapi%2F0.6%2Fchangeset%2Fcreate)

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/The_Rails_Port